# Can't add name to list with React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to follow a ReactJS tutorial as this is my first adventure into the framework, trying to adapt it to another style I have seen.

However I cannot seem to get the following to work. It is a simple `type a name > click button > add to displayed list` app, but after changing the style to one I am more comfortable with, I cannot seem to get the add to occur.

[Please see my Fiddle for the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/xgsy2mwg/)

[This is the tutorial code that I am following.](https://jsfiddle.net/uwemugrf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `addFriend` function in the App component doesn't take the argument friend. Also when you are using your `prevState` values to update the state, follow the updater function syntax of `setState`. change it to

```
 addFriend = (friend) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      friends: prevState.friends.concat([friend])
    }))
  }
```

**[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/61508r1w03)**

Comment: Aha! I knew I was missing something! I had seen the prevState used in my previous study yesterday, and I thought there was something missing from the arguments too. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: glad to help you